# Will a table row be displayed if all its cells are empty?

Tags: html, html-table

I have an empty table row just for separation between rows.

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="5"></td>
</tr>
```

It's rendered in IE, FF, Opera and Safari. The question is, whether I should put some content inside of it or it is okay to leave it as it is?

Like:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Using an empty row for spacing breaks your data structure.

You would probably be better off wrapping the various blocks of data in thead or tbody elements and styling them to acheive the spacing.

Answer (score 13):

Well you could put an `&nbsp;` as column content to make sure the rows are displayed. The better way is to use CSS for spacing though.

Comment: CSS will not work. I also wish to fill cells with background color, while having separators stay white. If I were to put padding onto cells, the padded area would also be filled. I don't want that.

Answer (score 6):

Semantically, does the empty row serve a purpose, or is it purely for layout? If the latter, it may be worth considering dropping the empty row, and providing the separation via CSS. E.g.

```
<tr class="separate-below">
    <td>Data before separater</td><td>More Data</td>...
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Data after separater</td><td>More Data</td>...
</tr>
```

With the following in the stylesheet:

```
TR.separate-below TD,TR.separate-below TH {
    border-bottom: 1em solid white; /* use the background colour of a cell here */
}
```

Alternatively, you can use multiple <tbody> elements to group blocks of rows together (adding rules="groups" to the table element causes <tbody> elements to gain a horizontal border at top and bottom, and <colgroup> element to gain a border to their left and right):

```
<table rules="groups">
<thead>
    <tr><th>Header</th><th>Header</th>...</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td>...</tr>
    <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td>...</tr>
    ...
</tbody>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td>...</tr>
    ...
</tbody>
...
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_nbsp) from W3Schools using the `&nbsp;` is the best way to do what you want.

Comment: 1. w3fools, 2. link rot. Apart from that, I'm not against `&nbsp;`-ing table cells.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old question, but if somebody still needs a solution (problem exists with `display: table-cell` or `table-row elements`)

here's the solution:

```
.emptyElement:after{
  content: "\00a0";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add my solution which is a modification of @Dariusz Sikorski solution.

```
td:empty:after, th:empty:after {
  content: "\00a0";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to put content inside, i would use a no-breaking-space: `&nbsp;`, rather than a normal blank

Answer (score 0):

You may have already tried this but if your trying to add some space in between rows have you tried adding some padding.

CELLSPACING=Length (spacing between cells)

CELLPADDING=Length (spacing within cells)

Karl

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that empty cells are displayed the following CSS can be used:

```
table { empty-cells:show; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `tbody` tags to group table rows. It's totally valid and more semantic.